# backbone.js bitfield values add to model best practice

Tags: backbone.js

If I have some bitmask constants i.e. kRequired=0x1, kLocked=0x2, kTypeA=0x4, kTypeB-0x8 etc

Where should these be added to the Model as I'd rather not have globals even if they are immutable values. at A. B. C. D in the code below or another way altogether.?

there are a a bunch of them (30), just showing a couple in example below. It seem to me they are not actual instance values to set/get but like a global lookup scoped to the model class..

```
  var Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
      initialize: function(){

      /** A) here the models init ?  **/
      this.kRequired = 0x1 ,
      this.kLocked - 0x2. 

      /* .... */ 
      },


      /*  B) here as models meta data ?? */
      kRequired ": 0x1.
      kLocked    : ox2.

      isLocked = function{){
        return ((this.get('bitinfo') & kLocked) != 0)
      }


     });


    new Entry({/* C) here with instance data */
               {
                bitinfo: 0x102, 
                name:"abd"
               },
               /* or D) with class data here? */
               );
```

Comment: could you describe nature of entry and its purpose? or something about View you may be having for clear guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

Below would be ideal structure for your Entry Model:

```
 var Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
          // define the mode variables in defaults 
          defaults:{
            kRequired:0x1,
            kLocked:0x2
            instaceVariable:""  // can add default value
        },
          initialize: function(){          
                var req=this.get("kRequired") // to retrieve kRequired
                var lock=this.get("kLocked")   // to retrieve kLocked
          }     
         });
  var myEntry=new Entry({instaceVariable:"New Instace value"}); 
   //create an instance of Model
```

You can add your constant values in defaults of Model, So they can be accessed with the instace of Model. You need to access them by .get() function.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue.  I didn't want to use the defaults solution proposed by Umesh because I will be saving the models and didn't want the extraneous fields.

I ended up creating a config object off the model class.  For your example, it would look like:

```
var Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
 // ...
});
Entry.constant = {};
Entry.constant.kRequired = 0x1;
...
```

And then you can just use Entry.constant.kRequired as you would any normal javascript variable.  It doesn't depend on there being a new Entry object created, and is a bit clearer that these are class level constants.